# How can I take headers from this ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-302, response-headers

This script returns 302 exception, but I can't take Headers from response.

In console I can see header `location`. It returns a new URL, but I can't get it from script.

HELP!

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://vk.com/doc-58017030_217989332?hash=89a86b87f793847c96&dl=96884e265f15cb647f&api=1',
    type: 'GET',
    data:     {},
    cache:    false,
    timeout:  30000,
    success:  function (data, textStatus, request) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    error:    function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    complete: function (request, textStatus) {
        console.log('complete');
        console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
});
```

Comment: looks like you are getting it.. have you looked at what that function does?  `function () { return state === 2 ? responseHeadersString : null;}`

Answer (score 0):

As this is a cross domain access call you really need to solve it on your server. There does not appear to be a work-around for 302 redirects using client-side only code. They are considered "unsafe" by the browser (as far as JavaScript is concerned).

### Suggested solution:

Provide a service on your own web server, that accepts a URL (like `http://vk.com/doc-58017030_217989332?hash=89a86b87f793847c96&dl=96884e265f15cb647f&api=1`) and returns the stream of the final response (after any redirects). This will generally solve any cross domain security problems as well (by making them all come via your own domain).

It is far easier to solve remote data access problems from a server than JScript in a browser.